# Why does Ubuntu 13.10 still not include MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is the reason 13.10 still does not include MariaDB?

I consider switching from MySQL to MariaDB on 13.10 and wonder what's holding back Ubuntu.

PS : Even if MariaDB is not yet included in the distro, I hope the migration will at least be painless.

Comment: Was surprised too that MariaDB is so "difficult" to install on Ubuntu - no PPA's even.

Comment: Look at [Installing MariaDB - Unmet dependencies, mariadb-server-5.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214517/installing-mariadb-unmet-dependencies-mariadb-server-5-5) please.

Comment: I am asking WHY it is not included in the distro.

Comment: @karel Close voters: This is not a duplicated. He wants a reason, not the method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an authoritative answer about the "Why's MariaDB isn't included in Ubuntu", but insights into the general process about how software is included into Ubuntu.

> What is the reason 13.10 still does not include MariaDB?

Software included in Ubuntu is introduced using two ways:

- Imported from Debian (Upstream)
- Introduced by the developers into the main Ubuntu archive.

As you can see, first depends of another distribution work and second of the developer of said program. Of course, in the second case could be a maintainer that decided to prepare MariaDB for Ubuntu and submitted their source code.

Either way, it requires "someone" to do the work. This is the case of the packages included in the so called "multiverse" and "universe" repositories.

So, the exact reason why MariaDB isn't included into Ubuntu "main" repository?

The most likely reason is because Debian is undergoing the process to add MariaDB into their main repository and Ubuntu maintainers don't want duplicated efforts.

The bug/wish to include MariaDB into Debian can be followed [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=565308). There is also a [master plan](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/MariaDBPlan) about what the mariadb package should do, and what functions should include.